# How to pass CSRF token in header in Store

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm calling Store while loading the extjs application. Now, I need to add CSRF security token in the store and this store should call while loading the application itself. I have added the token like below but request failed and given 500 error.

```
headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'token name'
    }
```

Anything wrong in the above code?

Comment: A bit more example code would help to see if the ExtJS code is correct. However, 500 errors are server-side problems, so I suggest you try and see if there is more information there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `headers` parameter in `proxy`.

Check documentation: [Ajax-headers](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-headers)

When using cross-origin resource :

Set variable [`withCredentials`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-withCredentials) as `true` and variable [`useDefaultXhrHeader`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-useDefaultXhrHeader) as `false` in proxy also.